# Moments of completed L-functions?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219292/behaviour-of-zeta1-it-zeta1it).

It seems that results on moments of L-functions, that is, estimates for integrals of the form
$$\int^{T}_1|\zeta(\sigma+it)|^{2k}dt$$
are typically for the incomplete L-function itself. Are there results for moments of completed L-functions, say, the completed Riemann zeta function?

If not, is the reason simply because the completed expression is more complicated than the incomplete one?

Comment: If you complete the zeta function, the Gamma factors will decay exponentially, so you will only pick up a contribution from small values of $t$, and this will be some constant for each $k$.